# iOS app breaks unexpectedly. Multithreading issue (probably)

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I have an app where I read data from input stream and visualize it to user. When I set up input stream, I set it up in background run loop, open it and then run a background loop. But sometimes my app breaks unexpectedly. I can't repeat this crash so I don't even know where to start to fix it.

The crash I get looks like this:
[image]

And the method where it crashes looks like this:
[image]

It says that it is `Enqueued from background queue (Thread 3)`. And `Thread 3` looks like that:
[image]

What could be the reason of this? Where should I start to fix it?

---

And the strange thing is that in `Thread 17`, where it crashes variable `bg_queue` is nil, and anyway it passes the if condition where i do

> if (bg_queue != nil)

But in Thread 3 it is not nil:

**Thread 17**
[image]

**Thread 3**
[image]

Comment: I would try to ensure that you don't access a managed object from the wrong thread/context.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but I am not trying to access any of managed objects in this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, you create a run loop from a secondary thread managed by GCD. You should not obtain a run loop from a thread that is managed by GCD!

Create your own dedicated thread or use the main thread to obtain a run loop.

Comment: Then how would you suggest me to get same results without using GCD but not affecting the rest of the app performance?

Comment: Unfortunately, this may become a more complex answer. You have a few options: 1. a) Create a dedicated thread or use the main thread, where you obtain the run loop, b) schedule the actual work on the desired dispatch queue. 2. Get the native socket handles from the CFStreams and use dispatch sources to asynchronously read/write from/to them. 3. Use a purely GCD approach with Dispatch IO - that is, don't use run loop based CFStreams and dispatch queues in one solution. 4. Use CFStream synchronously.

Comment: Thank you for solution. I will try it and let you know if I succeed.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a second runloop, you are more courageous than I am. I would never dare doing that, because I would be just sure that it leads to problems that are too hard for me to fix. As you are finding out.

If you are sure that you are a much more clever developer than I am, then sorry, you're on your own. If you are not sure, then DON'T DO THAT! Stay away from secondary run loops!

Comment: Then how do you offer me to continuously read and process data from input source without affecting UI performance? Because for that I do need run loop as I understand, and I create separate one for data processing only.